# Can't change color of opened caret?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I want to change color of caret, when it is opened.

My HTML code:

```
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-togle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <b>Download</b>
          <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>...</li>
          </li>
```

I tried this code:

```
       .dropdown  .caret .open {
    border-top: 8px solid black;
}
```

and one more question - can I change dropdown's form ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct selector for the caret is as follows:

```
.dropdown.open a.dropdown-toggle .caret {  }
```

You should use tools such as Developer Tools or Firebug to inspect your document and see what classes get applied to what elements when you change their state. It really helps when trying to figure out how to target certain elements.

Not sure about what you mean by "*change dropdown's form*", can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Thanks for helping, but code .dropdown.open .caret {
  border-top: 8px solid black;
  
 } doesn't change the color for me. It became white when I click. I will show you what I mean sating - change dropdown's form.

Comment: My selector might not have been specific enough, try the updated answer.

Comment: it is became white, did'nt help

Comment: You just need to check how specific your selector is. Here is a jsFiddle of a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bdCMU/1/